# How do I fix this StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, recursion

Background:
The code is intended to use a recursive binary search algorithm to loop through an ArrayList of PhoneBookEntries with a name and a number.

I think I'm getting infinite recursion with my search method here. I've copied in the code. I'm confused: from what I can tell, each time, the array should be divided in half and searched through again until the search term is found, but the method doesn't seem to be terminating correctly. Any tips?

EDITS: I've changed the code as suggested by the comments below, but it still doesn't work?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class BinarySearcher {

    private ArrayList<PhoneBookEntry> entries;

    public BinarySearcher(ArrayList<PhoneBookEntry> entries)
    {
        this.entries = entries;
    }

    public int search(String find, int low, int high){

        int mid = (low + high) / 2;

        if(entries.get(mid).getName().compareTo(find) == 0){
            return mid;
        }

        if(entries.get(mid).getName().compareTo(find) < 0){
            return search(find, mid+1, high);
        }
        else if(entries.get(mid).getName().compareTo(find) > 0){
            return search(find, low, mid-1);
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: A StackOverflow? You've come to the right place :sunglasses:

Comment: Why don't you create an array with 10 or less items and debug it?

Comment: Where do you use the parameters passed to `search()`?

Comment: `int mid = (low + high) / 2;` should probably be `int mid = (pLow + pHigh) / 2;`.  It seems as though you copy/pasted from multiple sources.

Comment: Get rid of `low` and `high`, use `plow` and `phigh` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You initialize low, high, and mid every recursion from an external value that dosen't change. So they don't actually get any smaller.

pLow and pHigh is never used, but they are the new values you just worked with in the previous recursion..

Comment: Beat me to it, but this. You should be passing those initial values as arguments in a check, not within the method.

Comment: It's interesting, I actually tried that right after posting this because I realized my mistake, but it STILL didn't work. I'm befuddled.

Answer (score 1):

Your function never uses those `pLow` and `pHigh` parameters, so it always has `low = 0` and `high = entries.size() - 1`. Your function should use only its parameters, and those two initializations must be made outside the first call to `search`.

Say:

```
public int search(String find){
  return this.search(find, 0, entries.size() - 1 );
}

private int search(String find, int low, int high) {
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;

    if(entries.get(mid).getName().compareTo(find) == 0){
        return mid;
    }

    if(entries.get(mid).getName().compareTo(find) < 0){
        return search(find, mid+1, high);
    }
    else if(entries.get(mid).getName().compareTo(find) > 0){
        return search(find, low, mid-1);
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but got nothing. I don't get it; this should be working!

Comment: @user3349460 Machines tend to not be _that_ wrong in simple cases like this. Try devnull's suggestion of a tiny test scenario to check if `mid` is properly set, but this solves a great issue you had.

Answer (score 0):

You are recursively calling it with the min and max indexes of the list itself, rather than basing the new parameters on the parameters passed to the method.

```
public int search(String find, int pLow, int pHigh){
    // int low = 0; dont need, just use pLow
    // int high = entries.size() - 1; use pHigh instead
    int mid = (pLow + pHigh) / 2;

    if(entries.get(mid).getName().compareTo(find) == 0){
        return mid;
    }

    if(entries.get(mid).getName().compareTo(find) < 0){
        return search(find, mid+1, pHigh);
    }
    else if(entries.get(mid).getName().compareTo(find) > 0){
        return search(find, pLow, mid-1);
    }
    return -1;
}
```